# Azure Container - interact with files on remote container instance

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I'm trying to remotely interact with a container instance in Azure.
I've performed following steps:

1. Loaded local image on local registry

   docker load -i ima.tar
2. Loggin in to remote ACR

   docker login --username --password + login-server
3. Tagged the image

   docker tag local-image:tag <login-server/repository-name:tag>
4. Pushed imaged

   docker push <login-server/repository-name:tag>

If I try to run a command like this:

```
az container exec --resource-group myResourceGroup --name <name of cotainer group> --container-name <name of container app> --exec-command "/bin/bash"
```

I can successfully login to bash interactively.
My Goal is to process local file to the a remote ACI using the ACR image, something like this:

```
docker run -t -i --entrypoint=./executables/run.sh -v "%cd%"\..:/opt/test remote_image:tag
```

Is it there a way to do so? How can I run ACI e remote push file via AZ CLI?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose, I recommend you mount the Azure File Share to the ACI and then upload the files to the File Share. Finally, you can access the files in the File Share inside the ACI. Follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files) to mount the File Share.

Comment: Thx for the info, but is it not possible to interact with remote ACI using local file exposure? (like an extry point?)

Comment: @user3925023 I'm afraid you can't. I see you run the docker command to mount the local volumes, but ACI doesn't support it. If you want to execute the script, you must upload the script to the ACI.

Comment: @user3925023 Any more updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I'm still figuring out how to automate data upload for testing, but for sure I'll keep you posted many thx

Comment: @user3925023 If it's helpful to you please accept it.